# How to return all connection regarding things using PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

I am using these piece of code for connection, It is working fine.

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rnd','root','');
```

But When I `print_r($db);` It's only return the `PDO Object()` But i want to complete details regarding Db and Host like dbname, hostname, username and various resources.

Comment: try `var_dump`.

Comment: Using `var_dump` result is like somthing `object(PDO)#2 (0) {}`

Comment: the  try `get_object_vars`

Comment: `get_object_vars` It's displaying nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get connection details:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('odbc:sample', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$attributes = array(
    "AUTOCOMMIT", "ERRMODE", "CASE", "CLIENT_VERSION", "CONNECTION_STATUS",
    "ORACLE_NULLS", "PERSISTENT", "PREFETCH", "SERVER_INFO", "SERVER_VERSION",
    "TIMEOUT"
);

foreach ($attributes as $val) {
    echo "PDO::ATTR_$val: ";
    echo $conn->getAttribute(constant("PDO::ATTR_$val")) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Hope it will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: No, Its not giving me `DB` related details. The results are given as `Array
(
    [PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT] => 1   
    [PDO::ATTR_CASE] => 0
    [PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4 $
    [PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS] => localhost via TCP/IP    
    [PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO] => Uptime: 4862  Threads: 1  Questions: 421  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 92  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 85  Queries per second avg: 0.086
    [PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION] => 5.6.14
    [PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT] => 
)`